# Need suggestion on the kafka topic/partition creation

Tags: apache-kafka

Need a help in the best way to create kafka topics and partitions.

We already have MS SQL service brokers, for different db's in different db servers. We do use SB with a set of Queue's and these queues's are common in all different db's.

Now we want to reduce the loads on the db's so planning them to migrate to Kafka topics instead of pressuring the db layer.

So each db will have different set of client transactions which uses each queue's and that will be within that db scope, so if something come up on to one db only the clients in that db will be seeing issues while other db's still works good.

Keeping these things in mind now we need to come up with a similar architecture with Kafka topics.

So if we go with Kafka cluster with N brokers, and create a topic for each queue that we used to have on the DB, how can we still make reduce multi client dependencies, being if now as centralized topic for all the db's /clients?Can we leverage partitions here?

Below is the representation of how I explained above

DB1 -> Queue1; Queue2; Queue3 (multiple clients on this db will consume all these queues while each queue is serving different functionality)

DB2 -> Queue1; Queue2; Queue3 (same queues as of in DB1 serving same functionalities)

So being said this what could be the best design for this in Kafka?

Comment: It would help if you could describe the actual actions that occur from the database client rather than describe how you've built "a queue" using a relational database. For example, an enqueue action is just a produce event, however consuming any data from Kafka doesn't remove it from this "queue", and records are not modifiable, so are you prepared to handle duplicates?

Comment: Thanks for looking into. So based on client actions we do submit message to queue and it then calls websevice that process the message and peforms actions and once done then the message should be disappeared from queue on its own.

Comment: If you want messages to "disappear" upon consumption then Kafka is not suitable for this task

Comment: But based on my understanding once a message is consumed by Consumer , its done right? do we think it might come back again during any situation so that we need handle duplicates ??

Comment: That depends on how you handle offset commits. A consumer can process a message, then not commit the offset. When the consumer then restarts, it'll process that message again... If you commit the offset manually before processing, then processing fails, then you effectively are skipping messages. You can tweak this with a few "exactly-once" configurations, but it only applies to Kafka delivery semantics, not external message handling such as to/from databases

Comment: Yes for sure we want to commit the offset as soon as we process the message and we want to persist the message if it fails so that we can retry them in some time . But my main question was instead of creating clients x no of queues which become hard to manage, can we create N topics (here for us it would be 15) and within each topic can we create each partition for one db as the analogy that I mentioned for our current MS SQL SB queues??

Comment: Sure, you can create one partition in as many topics, for as many tables as you want. Have you looked at Debezium or other CDC alternatives for MSSQL?

Comment: Haven't explored them, but here I am not looking at the CDC but instead a app based queuing mechanism to replace our existing MS SQL service broker which is consuming more CPU on db's for other operations. So want to understand on how can we translate our existing DB queueing to some open source queueing like Kafka

Comment: But Kafka isn't a queue. It's a log. As stated, any database client write/update can be directly translated into a producer event. The consumer then is a sequential reader, and doesn't "pop" events, only reads

Comment: Yeah got that .. as we gonna write the second part of making other webservice calls in the consumer end once the consumer pulls the message. Also my question is how can I assign an identifer to a partition and make producer to post events to that particular partition?

Comment: The message keys or a custom `partitioner.class` config is responsible for that. Or you can explicitly produce to a partition, but you already said you only wanted one partition in your topic...

Comment: Oh cool so that I can use this custom partitioner.class config to point to the custom logic that we want to build in identifying partition. And yes I need one partition for one database (mapping with current SQL Service broker), so that there will be one topic for example "Notification" and will have 10 partitions each partition is dedicated for each db as each db can have multiple clients on it. So that if a client produces even for a topic we need to send it to the dedicated partition and so consumer can read and process it.

Comment: Having a consumer client subscribe to one partition of an `N` partition topic isn't exactly a good design choice. Partitions are meant as a scaling unit, and consumers ideally subscribe to all partitions when order doesn't matter. Plus, data across all partitions is usually consistent (no different database table schemas between each partition; refer Kafka Schema Registry for details on that). The suggested pattern would be have individual topics

Comment: Oh so we have some hunderds of DB's and each db got 15 queues so do you suggest to go with those many individual topics? Or is there any other architectural suggestions for a better management? We want the messages to be processed in the order and that's for sure we need it.

Comment: Kafka can handle tens of thousands of topics without much of an issue